# Import Word Document Data to RDLC Report

Tags: vb.net, import, ms-word, rdlc, reportviewer

### Goal

Append Word document data (text, bullet points, images) to a RDLC report.

### Attempt

Currently I (*unsuccessfully*) append the Word document data to the end of the report via a ReportParameter.

```
...

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter("rpReportTemplate", GetWordData(WordDocumentPath)))

...

Public Function GetWordData(ByVal wordPath As String) As String
    Dim MyWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim sConvertedString As String = ""

    MyWord = CreateObject("Word.application")
    MyWord.Visible = False
    MyWord.Documents.Open(wordPath)
    MyWord.Windows(1).Selection.WholeStory()
    MyWord.Windows(1).Selection.Copy()
    MyWord.Quit()

    sConvertedString = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html)
    Return sConvertedString
End Function
```

---

I cannot seem to get the images into the report. I get some odd HTML text and I also get odd text characters:

> Version:1.0 StartHTML:0000000207 EndHTML:0000068119
>   StartFragment:0000047434 EndFragment:0000068079
>   SourceURL:file://server1/folder1/file1.docx
>
> â€

Is it possible to import a Word template to a RDLC report?

Comment: You need to understand what `Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html)` retrieves,  See: [HTML Clipboard Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/html-clipboard-format).

Comment: @TnTinMn My hopes were to keep the complete formatting of said Word document and paste the contents into the rdlc. That's why I figured HTML would be best

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
        report.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
        rds.Name = "DataSet1";
        //This refers to the dataset name in the RDLC file
        rds.Value = EmployeeRepository.GetAllEmployees();
        report.DataSources.Add(rds);
        Byte[] mybytes = report.Render("WORD");
        //Byte[] mybytes = report.Render("PDF"); for exporting to PDF
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"D:\wordfile.doc"))
        {
            fs.Write(mybytes, 0, mybytes.Length);
        }
    }
```

and your rdlc report export to word file